# Drupal views ajax error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, drupal, drupal-7

**I have this error while configuring views in drupal.**

> An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
>       HTTP Result Code: 200
>       Debugging information follows.
>       Path: /system/ajax
>       StatusText: OK
>       ResponseText:
>       [ {"command":"settings", "settings":{"basePath":"\u002F", "pathPrefix":"", "ajaxPageState":{"theme":"seven",
>   "theme_token":"Rts8LAjXs9pX8bnJAbg2_psyTDWdGyvNvr-KIRnRLYA",
>   "css":{"misc\u002Fui\u002Fjquery.ui.core.css":1,
>   "misc\u002Fui\u002Fjquery.ui.theme.css":1,
>   "modules\u002Foverlay\u002Foverlay-parent.css":1},
>   "js":{"misc\u002Fui\u002Fjquery.ui.core.min.js":1,
>   "misc\u002Fjquery.ba-bbq.js":1,
>   "modules\u002Foverlay\u002Foverlay-parent.js":1}},
>   "overlay":{"paths":{"admin":"node\u002F*\u002Fedit\u000Anode\u002F*\u002Fdelete\u000Anode\u002F*\u002Frevisions\u000Anode\u002F*\u002Frevisions\u002F*\u002Frevert\u000Anode\u002F*\u002Frevisions\u002F*\u002Fdelete\u000Anode\u002Fadd\u000Anode\u002Fadd\u002F*\u000Aoverlay\u002Fdismiss-message\u000Auser\u002F*\u002Fshortcuts\u000Aadmin\u000Aadmin\u002F*\u000Abatch\u000Ataxonomy\u002Fterm\u002F*\u002Fedit\u000Auser\u002F*\u002Fcancel\u000Auser\u002F*\u002Fedit\u000Auser\u002F*\u002Fedit\u002F*",
>   "non_admin":"admin\u002Fstructure\u002Fblock\u002Fdemo\u002F*\u000Aadmin\u002Freports\u002Fstatus\u002Fphp"},
>   "ajaxCallback":"overlay-ajax"},
>   "ajax":{"edit-fields-field-gurutanggallahir-settings-edit--2":{"callback":"field_ui_display_overview_multistep_js",
>   "wrapper":"field-display-overview-wrapper", "effect":"fade",
>   "event":"mousedown", "keypress":true, "prevent":"click",
>   "url":"\u002Fsystem\u002Fajax",
>   "submit":{"_triggering_element_name":"field_gurutanggallahir_formatter_settings_edit"}},
>   "edit-fields-field-gurusekolahklsprll-settings-edit--2":{"callback":"field_ui_display_overview_multistep_js",
>   "wrapper":"field-display-overview-wrapper", "effect":"fade",
>   "event":"mousedown", "keypress":true, "prevent":"click",
>   "url":"\u002Fsystem\u002Fajax",
>   "submit":{"_triggering_element_name":"field_gurusekolahklsprll_formatter_settings_edit"}},
>   "edit-fields-field-gurusekolahjummurid-settings-edit-form-actions-save-settings":{"callback":"field_ui_display_overview_multistep_js",
>   "wrapper":"field-display-overview-wrapper", "effect":"fade",
>   "event":"mousedown", "keypress":true, "prevent":"click",
>   "url":"\u002Fsystem\u002Fajax",
>   "submit":{"_triggering_element_name":"field_gurusekolahjummurid_formatter_settings_update",
>   "_triggering_element_value":"Update"}},
>   "edit-fields-field-gurusekolahjummurid-settings-edit-form-actions-cancel-settings":{"callback":"field_ui_display_overview_multistep_js",
>   "wrapper":"field-display-overview-wrapper", "effect":"fade",
>   "event":"mousedown", "keypress":true, "prevent":"click",
>   "url":"\u002Fsystem\u002Fajax",
>   "submit":{"_triggering_element_name":"field_gurusekolahjummurid_formatter_settings_cancel",
>   "_triggering_element_value":"Cancel"}},
>   "edit-fields-group-dispgurupelatihantopik-settings-edit--2":{"callback":"field_ui_display_overview_multistep_js",
>   "wrapper":"field-display-overview-wrapper", "effect":"fade",
>   "event":"mousedown", "keypress":true, "prevent":"click",
>   "url":"\u002Fsystem\u002Fajax",
>   "submit":{"_triggering_element_name":"group_dispgurupelatihantopik_group_settings_edit"}}},
>   "fieldUIRowsData":{"field-gurunamalengkap":{"rowHandler":"field",
>   "defaultFormatter":"text_default", "name":"field_gurunamalengkap",
>   "region":"visible"}, "field-gurujeniskelamin":{"rowHandler":"field",
>   "defaultFormatter":"list_default", "name":"field_gurujeniskelamin",
>   "region":"visible"}, "field-gurutempatlahir":{"rowHandler":"field",
>   "defaultFormatter":"text_default", "name":"field_gurutempatlahir",
>   "region":"visible"}, "field-gurutanggallahir":{"rowHandler":"field",
>   "defaultFormatter":"date_default", "name":"field_gurutanggallahir",
>   "region":"visible"},
>   "field-gurugelarpendidikan":{"rowHandler":"field",
>   "defaultFormatter":"text_default", "name":"field_gurugelarpendidikan",
>   "region":"visible"},
>   "field-gurulatarpendidikan":{"rowHandler":"field",
>   "defaultFormatter":"text_default", "name":"field_gurulatarpendidikan",
>   "region":"visible"}, "field-gurunohp":{"rowHandler":"field",
>   "defaultFormatter":"text_default", "name":"field_gurunohp",
>   "region":"visible"}, "field-gururumahalamat":{"rowHandler":"field",
>   "defaultFormatter":"text_default", "name":"field_gururumahalamat",
>   "region":"visible"}, "field-gururumahkecmtn":{"rowHandler":"field",
>   "defaultFormatter":"text_default", "name":"field_gururumahkecmtn",
>   "region":"visible"}, "field-gururumahkabptn":{"rowHandler":"field",
>   "defaultFormatter":"text_default", "name":"field_gururumahkabptn",
>   "region":"visible"}, "field-gururumahprov":{"rowHandler":"field",
>   "defaultFormatter":"list_default", "name":"field_gururumahprov",
>   "region":"visible"}, "field-gururumahkpos":{"rowHandler":"field",
>   "defaultFormatter":"text_default", "name":"field_gururumahkpos",
>   "region":"visible"}, "field-gururumahnotelp":{"rowHandler":"field",
>   "defaultFormatter":"text_default", "name":"field_gururumahnotelp",
>   "region":"visible"}, "field-guruinstansinama":{"rowHandler":"field",
>   "defaultFormatter":"text_default", "name":"field_guruinstansinama",
>   "region":"visible"}, "field-guruinstansialamat":{"rowHandler":"field",
>   "defaultFormatter":"text_default", "name":"field_guruinstansialamat",
>   "region":"visible"}, "field-guruinstansikcmtn":{"rowHandler":"field",
>   "defaultFormatter":"text_default", "name":"field_guruinstansikcmtn",
>   "region":"visible"}, "field-guruinstansikabptn":{"rowHandler":"field",
>   "defaultFormatter":"text_default", "name":"field_guruinstansikabptn",
>   "region":"visible"}, "field-guruinstansiprov":{"rowHandler":"field",
>   "defaultFormatter":"list_default", "name":"field_guruinstansiprov",
>   "region":"visible"}, "field-guruinstansikpos":{"rowHandler":"field",
>   "defaultFormatter":"text_default", "name":"field_guruinstansikpos",
>   "region":"visible"}, "field-guruinstansitelp":{"rowHandler":"field",
>   "defaultFormatter":"text_default", "name":"field_guruinstansitelp",
>   "region":"visible"}, "field-guruinstansifax":{"rowHandler":"field",
>   "defaultFormatter":"text_default", "name":"field_guruinstansifax",
>   "region":"visible"}, "field-guruinstansiemail":{"rowHandler":"field",
>   "defaultFormatter":"text_default", "name":"field_guruinstansiemail",
>   "region":"visible"}, "field-guruinstansiweb":{"rowHandler":"field",
>   "defaultFormatter":"link_default", "name":"field_guruinstansiweb",
>   "region":"visible"}, "field-guruweblog":{"rowHandler":"field",
>   "defaultFormatter":"link_default", "name":"field_guruweblog",
>   "region":"visible"}, "field-gurusekolahkelas":{"rowHandler":"field",
>   "defaultFormatter":"list_default", "name":"field_gurusekolahkelas",
>   "region":"visible"}, "field-gurusekolahtingkat":{"rowHandler":"field",
>   "defaultFormatter":"list_default", "name":"field_gurusekolahtingkat",
>   "region":"visible"}, "field-gurusekolahklsprll":{"rowHandler":"field",
>   "defaultFormatter":"number_integer",
>   "name":"field_gurusekolahklsprll", "region":"visible"},
>   "field-gurupelatihantopik":{"rowHandler":"field",
>   "defaultFormatter":"list_default", "name":"field_gurupelatihantopik",
>   "region":"visible"},
>   "field-gurusekolahjummurid":{"rowHandler":"field",
>   "defaultFormatter":"number_integer",
>   "name":"field_gurusekolahjummurid", "region":"visible"},
>   "field-gurupelatihantahunajar":{"rowHandler":"field",
>   "defaultFormatter":"list_default",
>   "name":"field_gurupelatihantahunajar", "region":"visible"},
>   "field-gurupelatihansemester":{"rowHandler":"field",
>   "defaultFormatter":"list_default",
>   "name":"field_gurupelatihansemester", "region":"visible"},
>   "field-gurupelatihankota":{"rowHandler":"field",
>   "defaultFormatter":"text_default", "name":"field_gurupelatihankota",
>   "region":"visible"},
>   "group-dispgurupelatihantopik":{"rowHandler":"group",
>   "name":"group_dispgurupelatihantopik", "region":"visible"},
>   "-add-new-group":{"rowHandler":"group", "name":"_add_new_group",
>   "region":"add_new"}}}, "merge":true}, {"command":"insert",
>   "method":"prepend", "selector":"head", "data":"\u003Cstyle
>   type=\u0022text\u002Fcss\u0022 media=\u0022all\u0022\u003E@import
>   url(\u0022http:\u002F\u002Flpsn.or.id\u002Fmisc\u002Fui\u002Fjquery.ui.core.css?m0x75e\u0022);\u000A@import
>   url(\u0022http:\u002F\u002Flpsn.or.id\u002Fthemes\u002Fseven\u002Fjquery.ui.theme.css?m0x75e\u0022);\u000A@import
>   url(\u0022http:\u002F\u002Flpsn.or.id\u002Fmodules\u002Foverlay\u002Foverlay-parent.css?m0x75e\u0022);\u003C\u002Fstyle\u003E\u000A",
>   "settings":null}, {"command":"insert", "method":"prepend",
>   "selector":"head", "data":"\u003Cscript
>   type=\u0022text\u002Fjavascript\u0022
>   src=\u0022http:\u002F\u002Flpsn.or.id\u002Fmisc\u002Fui\u002Fjquery.ui.core.min.js?v=1.8.7\u0022\u003E\u003C\u002Fscript\u003E\u000A\u003Cscript
>   type=\u0022text\u002Fjavascript\u0022
>   src=\u0022http:\u002F\u002Flpsn.or.id\u002Fmisc\u002Fjquery.ba-bbq.js?v=1.2.1\u0022\u003E\u003C\u002Fscript\u003E\u000A\u003Cscript
>   type=\u0022text\u002Fjavascript\u0022
>   src=\u0022http:\u002F\u002Flpsn.or.id\u002Fmodules\u002Foverlay\u002Foverlay-parent.js?v=1.0\u0022\u003E\u003C\u002Fscript\u003E\u000A",
>   "settings":null}, {"command":"insert", "method":null, "selector":null,
>   "data":"\u003Cdiv
>   id=\u0022field-display-overview-wrapper\u0022\u003E\u003Ctable
>   class=\u0022field-ui-overview sticky-enabled\u0022
>   id=\u0022field-display-overview\u0022\u003E\u000A
>   \u003Cthead\u003E\u003Ctr\u003E\u003Cth\u003EField\u003C\u002Fth\u003E\u003Cth\u003EWeight\u003C\u002Fth\u003E\u003Cth\u003EParent\u003C\u002Fth\u003E\u003Cth\u003ELabel\u003C\u002Fth\u003E\u003Cth
>   colspan=\u00223\u0022\u003EFormat\u003C\u002Fth\u003E
>   \u003C\u002Ftr\u003E\u003C\u002Fthead\u003E\u000A\u003Ctbody\u003E\u000A
>   \u003Ctr class=\u0022region-message region-visible-message
>   region-populated\u0022 no_striping=\u00221\u0022\u003E\u003Ctd
>   colspan=\u00227\u0022\u003ENo field is displayed.\u003C\u002Ftd\u003E
>   \u003C\u002Ftr\u003E\u000A \u003Ctr class=\u0022draggable
>   tabledrag-leaf odd\u0022
>   id=\u0022field-gurunamalengkap\u0022\u003E\u003Ctd\u003ENama
>   Lengkap\u003C\u002Ftd\u003E\u003Ctd\u003E\u003Cdiv
>   class=\u0022form-item form-type-textfield
>   form-item-fields-field-gurunamalengkap-weight\u0022\u003E\u000A
>   \u003Clabel class=\u0022element-invisible\u0022

**Any solutions for this.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think i found the solution. The problem is with the jQuery versions.

I installed [jQuery update](https://drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module and changed the jQuery version to 1.5(Both 1.5 and 1.7 works)

Answer (score 4):

When this happened to me, it was because of the jQuery Update module.

A solution for me was to downgrade jQuery on admin pages. Details over here: https://drupal.org/comment/8215267#comment-8215267

Comment: This error occurs as a result of conflicts between javascripts.